# SELECT DISTINCT on datetime

Tags: datetime, select, distinct

I need to display distinct values of a datetime field called datetimestamp from a SQLServer 2005 table in the MMM YYYY format.  I also need them to be sorted in chronological order.

So far I have this:

```
Select distinct CONVERT(CHAR(4), datetimestamp, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), datetimestamp, 120) as MonthYear from TableName order by MonthYear
```

The "order by" of course sorts it in alpha order due to the conversion.

```
 Apr 2009 
 Dec 2009 
 Feb 2009
```

How do I get it to sort it in chronological order?

```
Feb 2009
Apr 2009
Dec 2009
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

edit2:  It looks like you'll need to pull back more than one column.  This uses just the subquery from the previous attempt:

```
    select distinct DATEPART(year,datetimestamp) as year, 
           DATEPART(month,datetimestamp) as month,
           CONVERT(CHAR(4), datetimestamp, 100) 
           + CONVERT(CHAR(4), datetimestamp, 120) as MonthYear
    from TableName order by DATEPART(year,datetimestamp), 
                            DATEPART(month,datetimestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks @Fosco.  Tried your suggestion.  This however breaks a SELECT DISTINCT rule.  Here is the error:  ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: @VVM Ah yes... updated the answer with something else for you to try.

Comment: Thanks again.  Tried this one, too but got the foll. error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified. VVM

Comment: @VVM damn.. I'm making silly mistakes today... looks like you're going to need to pull more than one column.

Answer (score 0):

take a look a this post.

[Get month and year from a datetime in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535/get-month-and-year-from-a-datetime-in-sql-server-2005)