# MSSQL remove old records

Tags: sql-server, records

Can I remove ALL records within a database that are not from 2012 and 2013? Is this possible with any method you might know about? I am sure there are some tables which lack a timestamp column.

Comment: How does the DB know from when the records are?

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through tables and do a query like this:

```
DELETE FROM -TABLENAMEHERE- WHERE dateField<X AND dateField >Y
```

You can also extract the year from the field and do the right check:

Here's an example: [Get month and year from a datetime in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535/get-month-and-year-from-a-datetime-in-sql-server-2005)